# Finding a sequence $x_n$ with $\lim \sup(x_n)= 2$ and $\lim \inf(x_n)=-5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Find a sequence $x_n$ with $\lim \sup(x_n)= 2$ and $\lim \inf(x_n)=-5$.

I am stuck on this one. I am trying to find a sequence $x_n$ with the given information.

Comment: $x_n = n \mod 8 - 5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $$X_n=\begin{cases}-5&n\text{ even}\\2&n\text{ odd} \end{cases}\ \ ?$$